# Positive integer solutions for $a+b+c = 3(ab-c^2)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A friend of mine came up with this problem:
$$
a+b+c = 3(ab-c^2)
$$
Prove no solutions exist for positive integers $a, b$.

They say it's based on an IMO shortlist problem, but claims it's a bit harder.
I gave it a try myself, after isolating $a$ you get this: $a = (3c^2+c+b)/(3b-1)$.
This "simplifies" to the following statement: Prove $3c^2+c \not\equiv -b \pmod{3b-1}$ for all positive integers $b$.
Of course, you could go one step further: Because $3c^2+c$ is always even and $3b-1$ is even for odd $b$, you can prove that the equation above doesn't hold for odd $b$.
You're left with: $3c^2+c \not\equiv -2b \pmod{6b-1}$

I feel like I've reached a dead end, since a lot of the values $6b-1$ are primes. I believe my method is completely wrong.
How would you approach problems like these?

Comment: Did your friend say they had a solution?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews not sure, I'll let you know

Comment: any solutions with negative variables?

Comment: @WillJagy Yup, a lot, even. Eg. (-82, -10, 29) or (-12, -6, -9). But my program doesn't output any solutions for positive a b, so I'm assuming there are none.

Comment: Multiplying both sides by $3$ and rearranging, you get $$(3a-1)(3b-1)=9c^2+3c+1.$$

Comment: @ThomasAndrews  you have it; you have shown why positivity matters. The form $9 u^2 + 3uv + v^2$  has discriminant $-27,$  equivalent to $(1,1,7).$   The number $9 c^2 + 3c + 1$  is **primitively** represented by   $9 u^2 + 3uv + v^2$   and cannot be divisible by any (positive)  prime $q \equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Comment: @WillJagy Interesting! I don't understand your approach, could you elaborate a bit further? Thanks a lot everyone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiplying both sides by $3$ and rearranging, you get $$(3a-1)(3b-1)=9c^2+3c+1.$$
The left side must be divisible by a prime $p\equiv-1\pmod 3.$ But then $\gcd(c,p)=1.$

Then we must have a root to $x^3\equiv 1\pmod p,$ namely, $x=3c.$If $3c\not\equiv1\pmod p,$ then this root is a non-trivial root, and that is only possible if $p\equiv1\pmod3.$

So $3c\equiv 1\pmod p,$ and thus $0\equiv (3c)^2+3c+1\equiv 3\pmod p,$ and thus $p=3,$ which again is a contradiction.

---

There are negative solutions. For example when $c=3,$ we get $9c^2+3c+1=91=(-7)\cdot (-13)$ giving solutions $a=-2, b=-4.$

But there are no solution where even one of $a,b$ is positive.